# ggplot: size of annotate() vs size of element_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-size

I have some trouble harmonizing the sizes of different elements of my plot. Specifically I want the size of an annotation to be the same as the size of the title of the y-axis.

The following code results in different sizes however:

```
library(ggplot2)
test_data <- data.frame(x = c(1), y = c(1))
ggplot(test_data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  annotate("text", label = "A", x = 0.975, y = 1.025, size = unit(14, "pt")) +
  ylab("Why not the same size?") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = unit(14, "pt")))
```

[image: See here]

What gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`annotate` effectively just creates a new `geom_text` layer. If you look inside the source code of `GeomText$draw_panel` you will see that the text drawn in a `geom_text` layer is ultimately drawn by `grid::textGrob`, and its font size is determined by the expression:

```
fontsize = data$size * .pt
```

where we can see the `size` parameter is automatically upscaled by the (hidden) global variable `.pt`. You can see the value of `.pt` if you type in your console:

```r
.pt
#> [1] 2.845276
```

For some reason this scaling is not applied to the `size` parameter in `element_text`, even though `element_text` ultimately also uses `grid::textGrob` (via `ggplot2:::title_spec`). There's probably a good reason for this that I'm just not aware of.

Anyway, the bottom line is that if you want the size of a `geom_text` (or, by extension, an `annotation("text")` ) to match the size of an `element_text`, you, either divide the annotation's size by `.pt` or multiply the `element_text` size by `.pt`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

test_data <- data.frame(x = c(1), y = c(1))
ggplot(test_data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  annotate("text", label = "Now the same size", x = 0.975, y = 1, 
           angle = 90, size = 14/.pt) +
  ylab("Now the same size") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much!